# How to configure Nginx to balance over weblogic when have active/passive queues

Tags: nginx, jms, weblogic, weblogic12c, nginx-reverse-proxy

first let me explain my actual setup: Nginx -> Weblogic 12c (2 nodes: Node1-Machine A, Node2-Machine B), Nginx acting as reverse proxy over these two machines:

snippet nginx config:

```
upstream upstream_Weblogic {
    server A:port max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    server B:port max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
}
```

We have setup "stream" to be used with T3 protocol:

```
stream {
    upstream stream_T3 {
        server A:port max_fails=2 fail_timeout=30s;
        server B:port max_fails=2 fail_timeout=30s;
    }
```

we have tested this new configuration, sending JMS messages to a queue, and it works fine (in Weblogic we have setup a queue (active/active).

the problem comes when we set a queue in active/passive mode.

```
NGINX--->Weblogic---->node1(Active)---->JMS queue (Active)
                 ---->node2(Active)---->JMS queue (Passive)
```

Why?, because since both weblogic nodes are running, nginx keeps sending data to both nodes, but in this example the node 2 have passive queues

so the question is.....Is there a way to configure nginx for this case?

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What do you mean by active/passive queue ? Do you stop message producing/consuming at the queue level in WebLogic Server ?
Did you setup a cluster in your WebLogic domain with distributed queues ?

Comment: I have set up nodes with active/passive queues because we need to maintain order secuenciality of the messages in case of fail of one node, we have one application that need to be set up this way. We can't set nodes (active/passive) because we have another Applications that uses the active/active schema. the Weblogic nodes are Clusterized and the queues are distributed.